# How to include element tags within the return results for an XQuery FLWOR?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, nosql, xquery, flwor

How do I mix "new" tags in the `return` clause for an `xquery`?

this is the form of the output I'm after:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csv>
  <record>
    <sex>M</sex>
  </record>
  <record>
    <sex>F</sex>
  </record>
  <record>
    <sex>M</sex>
  </record>
  <record>
    <sex>F</sex>
  </record>
</csv>
```

The specific values I just entered by hand for illustration purposes.  Actual values, and current output, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><csv>SexMFFMFFMF</csv>
```

original `xml` data:

```
<csv>
  <record>
    <entry>Reported_Date</entry>
    <entry>HA</entry>
    <entry>Sex</entry>
    <entry>Age_Group</entry>
    <entry>Classification_Reported</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-01-26</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>M</entry>
    <entry>40-49</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-02</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>50-59</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-05</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>20-29</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-05</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>M</entry>
    <entry>30-39</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-11</entry>
    <entry>Interior</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>30-39</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-20</entry>
    <entry>Fraser</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>30-39</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-21</entry>
    <entry>Fraser</entry>
    <entry>M</entry>
    <entry>40-49</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-27</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>60-69</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
</csv>
```

The `FLWOR` query:

```
declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
declare namespace array = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array";

declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

for $x in /csv

return <csv>{$x/record[position() = (1 to 9)]/entry[3]/text()}</csv>
```

I've tried [putting node tags within the curly braces](http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9Xv6/1) but run into syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use e.g.

```
<csv>
{
for $record in /csv/record[position() = (2 to 9)]
return
  <record>
    <sex>{data($record/entry[3])}</sex>
  </record>
}
</csv>
```

or the simple map operator

```
<csv>
{
  /csv/record[position() = (2 to 9)]
  !
  <record>
    <sex>{data(entry[3])}</sex>
  </record>
}
</csv>
```